# Wordpress - How to exclude google autoaddress js from Optimize JavaScript Code

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I am trying to optimize my load speed for my site using Autoptimize plugin. I tried turning on the "Optimize JavaScript Code" feature and everything looked okay except that the google address autocomplete on my checkout page stopped working. How do i find what JS file this is so I can exclude it?

I thought it was the `woogoodad.js` file but when I excluded it, it was still not working.

Can someone please tell me what is the correct JS file to exclude so I can make this work.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Google autocomplete isn't on the list of scripts registered by default in wp, this must be a script registered through your theme. Try to look for "google.maps.places.Autocomplete" in your javascript files. The script can be also registered through functions.php file or added by a plugin. You can use some software to search your files, e.g. FileSeek

If autocompleete doesn't work at all, check if jQuery UI Autocomplete is excluded (jquery.ui.autocomplete.min.js)